# How can I use Marquee text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, null, flutter-test, marquee

I am getting a lot of errors when I implement marquee text code

these are the following errors:

```
E/flutter ( 8801): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(242)] Dart Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value, stack trace: #0      ScrollPosition.minScrollExtent (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:136:49)

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

======== Exception caught by scheduler library =====================================================
Null check operator used on a null value
```

this is my code for marquee text:

```
              Container(
              child: Expanded(
                  child: Marquee(
                    text: 'Some sample text that takes some space.',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    scrollAxis: Axis.horizontal,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    blankSpace: 20.0,
                    velocity: 100.0,
                    pauseAfterRound: Duration(seconds: 1),
                    startPadding: 10.0,
                    accelerationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                    accelerationCurve: Curves.linear,
                    decelerationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                    decelerationCurve: Curves.easeOut,
                  )
              ),
            ),
```

I have imported library  "import 'package:marquee/marquee.dart'; "

I have added `dependencies:marquee: ^2.1.0` in pubspec.yaml.

Comment: This is not happening due to your `Marquee` but the widget outside of it. Post your build method where you are using it. What is the need to use an `Expanded` ?

Comment: I got the marquee text after removing the expanded widget , thankyou sir

Comment: cool. you can add an answer to help others.